# How to auth using user authentication in python ? because I need to list out all the project IDs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-resource-manager

I need the list of project ids in gcp using python

I am trying this

```
    from google.cloud.resourcemanager import ProjectsClient
    for project in ProjectsClient().list_projects():
        print(project.display_name)
```

but I am getting the following error

> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not
> have permission

I think this could be resolved if I use a user account authentication instead of service account authentication.

Please suggest me a method to achieve this

Comment: Have you tried passing credentials to `ProjectClients`?

Comment: No. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions shows little effort from you in finding the answer for yourself. This is discouraged and your question may be downvoted|closed.

You don't include details of the authentication that you're using. Permission Denied would result from including no credentials as well as including incorrect credentials.

You may use either a user account or a service account to auth the client code and you (are probably?) using [Application Default Credentials (ADCs)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python).

To switch from using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` pointing to a Service Account key to User-based credentials, you must `unset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login).

**NOTE** It is the permissions (usually through roles) that are bound to the account **not** whether the account is a User account or Service Account that makes the difference to whether your code will be authorized.

Comment: I have not done any authentication via code. I just executed the above code snippet. But I did a user account authorization via command line

Comment: Then, when you rerun the code, it should now find the User credentials and, if the User account has suitable permissions, the code should work.